# Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined , nodeJS mongoose ejs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I'm training to be a developer. by following the instructions in https://medium.com/, but I'm quite surprised that it suddenly looks like this. **"Can not read property 'forEach' of undefined"** I'm not sure what I missed. But at first there was no such error.

This error

```
TypeError: D:\todolist\todoapp\views\todo.ejs:25
    23|             </form>
    24|             <ul class="todo-list">
 >> 25|                 <% todoTasks.forEach(details => { %>
    26|                 <li class="todo-list-item" >
    27|                     <div class="todo-list-item-name"><%= details.content  %></div>
    28|                     <a href="/done/<%= details._id %>" class="sussec">

Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at eval (eval at compile (D:\todolist\todoapp\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:662:12), <anonymous>:12:18)
    at todo (D:\todolist\todoapp\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:692:17)
    at tryHandleCache (D:\todolist\todoapp\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (D:\todolist\todoapp\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (D:\todolist\todoapp\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (D:\todolist\todoapp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (D:\todolist\todoapp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (D:\todolist\todoapp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at D:\todolist\todoapp\index.js:31:11
    at D:\todolist\todoapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:5068:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11
```

My **index.js** I use mongodb-atlas. to connect

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const dotenv = require("dotenv")
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

//models
const TodoTask = require("./models/TodoTask");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

dotenv.config();


app.use("/static", express.static("public"));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//connection to db
mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECT, { useNewUrlParser: true }, () => {
    console.log("Connected to db!");
    app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server Up and running"));
});

app.set("view engine", "ejs");



// GET METHOD
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    TodoTask.find({}, (err, tasks) => {
      res.render("todo.ejs", { todoTasks: tasks });
    });
  });
  
  // post method for server
  app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const todoTask = new TodoTask({
      content: req.body.content,
    });
    try {
      await todoTask.save();
      res.redirect("/");
    } catch (err) {
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  });
```

and this todo.ejs

```
<body>    
    <div class="todo-container">    
        <h2>To-Do List</h2>

        <div class="todo">
            <form action="/" method="POST" class="todo-header">
                <input type="text" name="content">
                <button type="submit"><p>add</p></span></button>
            </form>
            <ul class="todo-list">
                <% todoTasks.forEach(details => { %>
                <li class="todo-list-item" >
                    <div class="todo-list-item-name"><%= details.content  %></div>
                    <a href="/done/<%= details._id %>" class="sussec">
                        <p>done</p>
                    </a>
                    <a href="/remove/<%= details._id %>" class="remove">
                        <p>remove</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <% }) %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: it says ```todoTasks``` is ```undefined```, you will need to find out why it is undefined. try doing an ```if``` check on ```todoTasks``` and logging the ```err``` value before ```res.render('todo.ejs')```

Comment: @AshwynHorton Thanks for the advice, I've tried console.log and it's back up. I don't understand why it works.

Comment: No, ```console.log``` is not why it is up...there is something wrong with either your network connection or something because it sometimes fails to connect to your database server

Comment: From what I am gathering, it would serve good to read up more on navigating the web dev world...I think you dove right in, which is also good.

Comment: Thank you,I will improve myself more.

Comment: @slappy what did you modify? May I know the solution for this, please?

Comment: @VenkatSai I don't know about modify . I just follow in youtube sorry about there